# Node.js Express server terminates after a while

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am hosting Node.js Express server on AWS EC2 instance using nginx for reversed proxy. I am facing a problem, because it terminates connection after some time (possibly 1 hour). I am running the server with a simple commmand:

```
node app.js &
```

This makes my server to work fine but only for the first hour (or something about that). Then when I want to connect to the server I'm getting `502 Bad Gateway`, so I assume something terminates my application. Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code could be encountering an error, causing Node to stop. You should look into using something like [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to keep your Node application running.